# How to compute labels from predicted values of regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, linear-regression

I am working on a Machine Learning Project. I need to create two python scripts:

1) a classifier
2) Produce a text file of labels using that classifier.

I am just saving the model in the first script. Then, in the second script, I am applying that model to a different dataset containing text to produce predicted labels (ham, or spam) and saving those predicted labels in a text file.

Basically I have a list of text with labels, ham or spam.

I created a classifier using the Linear Regression Model. I had two different files of training data (`texts_training`, and `labels_training`), so I loaded my training data into variables called texts and labels. And then, I worked on the classifier. This is what I have for the classifier:

```
#classifier.py 
def features (words):
     fe = np.ndarrary ((len(tweets), 56) 
          for t, text in enumerate (words):
               if "money" in text:
                   money = 1
               else:
                   money = 0

               ...(55 more features)

               fe = [i:] = [money, ...]
         return fe
fe = features (words)

feat.shape
>>>(1000, 56)

import sklearn
X = fe
label = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label.fit(labels)
label = lab.transform(labels)
y.shape
>>>(1000,)


from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X,y, random_state = 4)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)


#Model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
clf = LinearRegression()
clf = lreg.fit(X, y) 

import pickle
f = open ("clf.pkl", "w")
pickle.dump ((clf, f)
f.close ()
```

Now, I was loading this into a different script but both scripts are saved in the same folder. This script basically has to use that classifier to save the labels produced in a txt.

```
system.py

    def features (words):
     fe = np.ndarrary ((len(tweets), 56) 
          for t, text in enumerate (words):
               if "money" in text:
                   money = 1
               else:
                   money = 0

               ...(55 more features)

               feat = [t, :] = [money, ...]
         return fe
fe = features (words)

X = feat
from sklearn import preprocessing
label = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label.fit(labels)
label = label.transform(labels) 
y = label
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)



import pickle
#class_output = pickle.load (open('clf.pkl', 'r'))
loaded_model = pickle.load (open('clf.pkl', 'r'))

class_output = loaded_model.predict (X)

**print class_output
>>>array([ 0.06140778,  0.053107  ,  0.14343903, ...,  0.05701325,
    0.18738435, -0.08788421])**

f = open ("labels_produced.txt", "w")
for output in class_output:
    if output ==0:
        f.write ("ham\n")
    else:
        f.write("spam\n")
f.close()
```

However, how do I compute spam or ham for the new data set as none of the values in the class_output are equal to 0. My features were set to be either 0 or 1.

I am a beginner learner, I have been struggling with this all day today. I do not understand why I get this error and how to fix it. If someone helps, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the `type` of `clf`, after you write `clf = lreg.fit(X, y)`?

Comment: <class 'sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression'>; how do I find the type? the text and label variable are in numpy.ndarray

Comment: 1. please avoid blanks between function calls and brackets. 2. pickle.dump((clf,f) yields a syntax error 3. That line also saves the fitted model but not the data! You need predict again.   Why do you create the file object f so early? The logic behind labels_produced.txt is not clear to me. Btw. Linear regression is typically not(!) a classifier.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I am just saving the model in the first script. Then I am applying that model to a different dataset containing text to produce predicted labels (ham, or spam) and saving those predicted labels in a text file.

Comment: you are saving the model. The model does not contain any output values. However, if you iterate over your input, you can aplly the model to that input and obtain an output, `ham` or `spam`. I think you want to store those outputs. But currently, you are not doing this

Comment: @san3567 You apply your linear regression model, but you are merely saving the built in model, **not** any of the the output that you found when you applied it. Decide which attributes you required from the LinearRegression object (which you create when you write `clf = lreg.fit`) and save those instead. Your target text is in the first piece of code in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an object. That is what the the error means:

```
'LinearRegression' object is not iterable'
```

This can be seen by doing:

```
type(clf) = sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression
```

`clf` is a LinearRegression object, with its own series of attributes. You cannot iterate over it like you try to do in the line:

```
for output in class_output:
    if output == 0:
        # etc
```

You need to extract the required attributes from your LinearRegression object `clf`, before you save them to Pickle or before you try and iterate over them.

There are several attributes contained in the LinearRegression obeject. 
For example, the following would five you the coefficients of your LinearRegression fit:

```
Coefficients = clf.coef_
```

If you decide what attribute of clf you actually want to iterate over, you can extract it in the way shown above.

**Edit: A list of attributes in the LinearRegression object is available here:**

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html
>
> coef_ : array, shape (n_features, ) or (n_targets, n_features)
>
> Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple targets are passed during the fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array of shape (n_targets, n_features), while if only one target is passed, this is a 1D array of length n_features.
>
> residues_ : array, shape (n_targets,) or (1,) or empty
>
> Sum of residuals. Squared Euclidean 2-norm for each target passed during the fit. If the linear regression problem is under-determined (the number of linearly independent rows of the training matrix is less than its number of linearly independent columns), this is an empty array. If the target vector passed during the fit is 1-dimensional, this is a (1,) shape array.
>   New in version 0.18.
>
> intercept_ : array
>
> Independent term in the linear model.

Edit: Great example available here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html

Further Question:

In your function `features`, it looks like you pass in your `(texts)` and then save whether a feature is `0` or `1` in the list `feat`. But at the end of the function, you return `re` instead of returning `feat`. If you return `feat` you may get the information you want. Also, you iterate with the variables `t,text` but then in `(feat = [i:] = [money, ...])` you assign the values in your `feat` array using the variable `i` . Should `i` be replaced with `t`?

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way that I can use the features that I use in classifier.py features method? (ie. money). Currently, that is what I was doing. But that does not work either

Comment: It is not obvious what your desired output is from your function features. You pass in your text file before you perform the LinearRegression fit which is correct. You need to save the output attributes using Pickle.

Comment: I used the Coefficient attributes, but that produced a text file with 56 spam labels (my dataset has 1000 line texts that needs to be classified), which is probably due to (for output in class_output:
 if output ==0:) part of my code. Is there anyother way I can label them ham or spam?

Comment: In your function features, it looks like you pass in your (`texts)` and then save whether a feature is 0 or 1 in the list `feat`. But at the end of the function, you return `re` instead of returning `feat`. If you return `feat` you may get the information you want. Also, you iterate with the variables `t,text` but then in (`feat = [i:] = [money, ...]` you assign the values in your `feat` array using the variable `i` . Should `i` be replaced with `t`?

Comment: In addition, should your function read:

`def features (words):`

     `fe = np.ndarrary ((len(tweets), 56)`

         `for t, text in enumerate (words):` ? instead of   `for t, text in enumerate (texts):`

Comment: I just added/missed extra characters while I was typing out the code again. Yes, it is feat at the bottom, not fe and it is feat [t,:]. Sorry. I can try using words instead of texts. What part of the model do I say to clf if it is not lreg.fit(X,y)?

Comment: You can write `clf = lreg.fit(X,y)` to carry out the linear regression. But if you want to extract the information from the clf object, you need to use the attribute notation as described above. (Also, can you Update your code so that it reads as it should?) So `fe = features(texts)` should return you a list of 0s and 1s like `[fe = 0,0,1,1...]`?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code. But now, I am getting an error that says, "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". It still does not produce the labels

Comment: I made few more changes to my code and the error randomly disappeared. So now I am getting a text file with 1000 labels, but all of them are spam. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: No, without being able to directly run your code. Can you post a sample of your text file and some of your other 55 features so that it can be directly copied and run?

Comment: Having looked at your new code, none of the values in your output array ( `class_output` ) are equal to 0. Therefore you will get 1000 labels that are all spam as you say. You have successfully saved the model output into pickle and output one of its attributes using `class_output = loaded_model.predict (X)`. So you have solved the original problem that you asked about.

You need to decide what you want your model to do - that is a separate non-coding problem to the original one that asked about.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to somehow use the class_output values and return spam or ham. I don't know how to do that

Comment: Ok, what do the class_ouput values represent? What are you measuring/what are you testing/what are you assigning? And what should the criteria be for returning spam or ham?

Comment: the class_output values represent the predict x value from the linear regression model. I don't know how make the criteria part for returning spam or ham. That is where I am stuck. Is there a way to make a criteria to return a label based on the predict X value

Comment: It all depends on what your criteria is. So you have the `class_output = [.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9...].` You would do as you have done: `for output in class output:` `if output > = # Some Number:   f.write "ham"` `if output < = # Some Number:  f.write "Spam"`  You have written it correctly, you need to decide what your criteria will be.

Comment: Did you get your code to work? If this answer was helpful, please upvote and accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.